# Nagios check with $ in parameter

Tags: windows, monitoring, nagios, nsclient++

I need to add Nagios checks for Windows SQL services that have a dollar sign in the name (e.g. `MSSQL$TOLLCONNECT`) but am so far unable to work out how to pass that name along without it being Nagios treating it as a variable name. What is the simplest way to do this, other than modifying the service name itself, which would break other things?

I'm running NSClient++ on the target machines and have considered creating checks with hard-coded names but that idea leaves a lot to be desired, as it creates a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: This is shot in the dark, but have you tried escaping the `$` with a `\\` (i.e `MSSQL\$TOLLCONNECT`)?

Comment: I think the Markdown got confused with that comment and added random backticks, so I'll say it in words too! Try escaping the dollar with a backslash.

Comment: @Ben, yes I tried that first and Nagios dropped everything after the dollar sign.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had I kept searching just that little longer I wouldn't have had to ask. [This web page](http://slashhome.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/nagios-nrpe_nt-configuration-with-mssqlservice/) has the answer. `MSSQL"$$"TOLLCONNECT` works a treat. Not the most intuitive syntax.